# How can I center equations?

Tags: equations

My code is:

```
onde
\begin{equation}
\pi(\textbf{x})=\frac{1}{1+e^{-(\beta_0+\sum_{i=1}^{p}\beta_ix_i)}}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

How can I put the equation in the middle?

Comment: it would be centred by default, you presumably have `fleqn` option or a non standard class in use.

Comment: You should post a fully compilable code that produces this result (document class, packages and options thereof).

Answer (score 6):

I can more or less reproduce your screenshot with the following code (observe that the `amsmath` package is loaded with the option `fleqn`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\setcounter{equation}{1}

\noindent
onde,
\begin{equation}
\pi(\textbf{x})=\frac{1}{1+e^{-(\beta_0+\sum_{i=1}^{p}\beta_ix_i)}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If you want to have the displayed equations centered rather than left-justified, *don't specify the* `fleqn` *option* while loading `amsmath`.

Separately, you should use `\mathbf` rather than `\textbf` in math mode. Also, do consider using `\exp[...]` notation instead of `e^{...}`; your readers will thank you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\setcounter{equation}{1}

\noindent
onde,
\begin{equation}
\pi(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{1+\exp[-(\beta_0+\sum_{i=1}^p \beta_ix_i)]}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: isn't `e` very different from `exp`? `e` is the number `2,718…`, while `exp` would be an general exponent, albeit a rather unusual way of writing it. I am, however, not a mathematician, so I could very well be wrong here.

Comment: @RunarTrollet - I'm not a mathematician either, but I've taken a fair number of math courses over the years. The only sensible base for the `\exp` expression is, you guessed it, `e\approx 2.718`. The reason I recommend `\exp` is typographic: the elements `\beta`, `x`, `\sum`, `-` and `+` will by typeset in scriptstyle rather than scriptscriptstyle -- much appreciated by anyone over 45 (or otherwise not blessed with keen eyesight of youth).

Comment: You are perfectly correct, I have just never seen it written in that way, but you do make a very good case. I also found an interesting post on Math.SE, about this very topic. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226089/is-expx-the-same-as-ex

Comment: @RunarTrollet - Correction to what I wrote earlier: Most of the material in the denominator of the second equation is rendered in `textstyle`, *not* `scriptstyle`. (The subscript and superscript terms in the second version of the equation are in scriptstyle, whereas they are in scriptscriptstyle in the first version.) Either way, the size difference is rather significant.

Comment: @Ana - Please confirm or disconfirm my conjecture that you were specifying the option `fleqn` in your document.